# In Spring, how do I invoke a public method from an autowired bean, in which the method is not part of the interface?

Tags: spring, methods, interface, autowired

I'm using Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE.  I have the following bean defined ...

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
...
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{

    ...
    public SpringboardAuthenticationUser getSpringboardAuthenticationUser(final User domainUser)
    {
    ...
```

The method "getSpringboardAuthenticationUser" is a method I created, not part of the org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService interface.  How can I access this method from other places?  For instance, in another part of my code I have

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService m_myUserDetailsSvc;
```

But clearly since the method is not part of the UserDetailsService interface, I cannot invoke it.  So how can I invoke this public method?

Comment: You can do something like create a new Interface extending UserDetailsService and add your desired method there. Then you can implement this new interface with your MyUserDetailsService class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Create a new Interface extending UserDetailsService and add your desired method.

```
public class MyUserDetailsService extends UserDetailsService {
    ...
    public SpringboardAuthenticationUser getSpringboardAuthenticationUser(final User domainUser); 
    ... 
}
```

> 2. Then implement this interface.

```
public class MyUserDetailsServiceImpl implements MyUserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    }

    @Override
    public SpringboardAuthenticationUser getSpringboardAuthenticationUser(final User domainUser){
        ... 
        //Your logic here.
    }
}
```

> 3. Autowire the new interface.

```
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to keep the method in the same class only because I invoke it from the "loadUserByUsername" method, the lone method implemented from teh UserDetailsService.  I'm unclear how everything would fit together if I moved this method outside of the class.

Comment: Hi Dave, when you extend UserDetailsService by your Interface, in this case, MyUserDetailsService, the implementing class should implement all the methods of MyUserDetailsService and UserDetailsService. So, the implementing class here, MyUserDetailsServiceImpl has to implement loadByUsername and getSpringboardAuthenticationUser methods.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can just cast `UserDetailsService` to `MyUserDetailsService` and invoke method directly:

```
if (m_myUserDetailsSvc instanceof MyUserDetailsService) {
    final SpringboardAuthenticationUser user = MyUserDetailsService.class.cast(m_myUserDetailsSvc).getSpringboardAuthenticationUser();
}
```

But from design perspective I'll recommend to reconsider it. The whole point of doing dependency injection is to lower coupling between components and such actions/intentions forcing you to do the opposite thing.

Why don't you make `getSpringboardAuthenticationUser()` method a part of your `UserDetailsService` interface? In that case it will become a contract and can be sure that whatever implementation was injected to you class by DI container it will satisfied a contract and be able to retrieve that user for you.

**Update per comment**

In case your beans get wrapped by proxy(s) you can call `isAssignableFrom` instead of `instanceOf`.

```
if (m_myUserDetailsSvc.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MyUserDetailsService.class)) {
         MyUserDetailsService.class.cast(m_myUserDetailsSvc).getSpringboardAuthenticationUser();
}
```

Comment: Hey "m_myUserDetailsSvc instanceof MyUserDetailsService" doesn't work because the objects are proxies.  When something is injected the class is not the interface itself but a proxy.  Also per my comments to the other poster, it is not an option to modify code I downloaded from Spring.

Comment: Thanks, but what if "m_myUserDetailsSvc.getClass().isAssignableFrom" returns false?  Then I still face the same dilemma of figuring out how to invoke the method, no?

Comment: Then it means that spring injected another implementation of `UserDetailsService`, not your own, so you will not be able to call that method (just get `ClassCastException`). The best option then is to throw some `IllegalStateException` with readable message.

Comment: I tried it out, but "m_myUserDetailsSvc.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MyUserDetailsService.class)" does indeed return false so I can't solve my problem using this method.

Comment: Have you mark your `MyUserDetailsService` bean definition as `primary`? Can you check in the debugger what class spring injects into your component? Or you can use a `@Qualifier` as @Alex suggested

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. If the only implementation that you have of the `UserDetailsService` is the `MyUserDetailsService`, then, modify the interface so that it includes the method `getSpringboardAuthenticationUser`.

If you cannot modify the interface, then you can autowire directly the class that you want to use `@Autowired MyUserDetailsService m_myUserDetailsSvc` or even cast the `UserDetailsService` to `MyUserDetailsService`. If you want to do the cast, then I'd recommend to use the `@Qualifier("MyUserDetailsService")` to force Spring to inject a bean of this type.

Comment: You are telling to modify Spring's UserDetailsService?

Comment: Yes, your interface (UserDetailsService) should contain all your methods. All different implementations should be compliant with the interface. You can have private methods, but ALL the public ones should be on the interface

Comment: Why would you modify Spring's UserDetailsService? I don't get it. It's just a bad practice. You can extend the UserDetailsService's functionality with new Interface and add new methods there without modifying existing API's interface.

Comment: I"m hesitant to modify Spring's UserDetailsService code.  Taht would get messy to maintain because as Spring comes out with new versions, I would repeatedly have to modify their versions.

Comment: I see that the interface is imported from the spring library. In that case, Autowire your own class rather than the interface. Spring supports it.